# Javascript select box overrides input on mouse click in safari

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input that does not allow me to enter input into. Whenever I try to click into the input, it automatically jumps back to the initial select input. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<h4 class="plan-info-header">Plan info</h4>
            <label class="plan-name">Plan name: 
                <select id="billing-plan" name="billing-plan" class="selectpicker">
                    <option>Choose plan</option>
                    <option>Basic</option>
                    <option>Prime</option>
                    <option>Gold</option>
                </select>

            <div class="payment-term">
                <label>Billing period:</label>
                <select id="billing-price" name="billing-term" class="selectpicker" disabled>
                    <option value="0">Choose billing term</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label>Advertising Budget:</label>
                <input id="advertising"></input>

<div class="card-charge-info">
Your card will be charged $<span id="payment-total">0</span> now, and your subscription will bill $<span id="payment-rebill">0</span> every month thereafter. You can cancel or change plans anytime. <!-- <span id="test">XXX</span> -->
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var term = 0;
 var price = 0;
 var additional = 0;
 var fix = 0;
 var plan = document.getElementById('billing-plan');
 plan.addEventListener('change', enableBilling, false);
 var select = document.getElementById('billing-price');
 select.addEventListener('change', updatePrice, false);

function populateBilling(planName) {
var options = {
    basic: { 
        "Option" : ["$200/month for 1-yr", "$250/month"],
        "Value" : [300, 350]
    },
    prime: { 
        "Option" : ["$300/month for 1-yr", "$350/month"],
        "Value" : [400, 450]
    },
    gold: { 
        "Option" : ["$400/month for 1-yr", "$450/month"],
        "Value" : [500, 550]
    }
}

//RESET BILLING PERIOD OPTIONS
select.options.length = 1;
document.getElementById('payment-total').innerText = 0 + additional;
document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = 0 + additional;
var data = options[planName];
if (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Option.length; i++){
        var temp = document.createElement('option');
        temp.value = data.Value[i];
        temp.text = data.Option[i];
        select.appendChild(temp);
    }
   }
 }

function enableBilling(e) {
    document.getElementById('billing-price').disabled=false;
    var planName = plan.options[plan.selectedIndex].text.toLowerCase();
    populateBilling(planName);

}

function updatePrice(e) {
    price = parseFloat(select.value);
    fix = 100;
    if (price == select.options[2].value){
        term = 1;
    } 
    document.getElementById('payment-total').innerText = price + additional;
    if (price == select.options[2].value){
    document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = 0 + additional; 
    } else {
    document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = price + additional - fix;
    }
}
```

My JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/aGq9q/17/

Comment: The fiddle appears to work in Chrome.

Comment: @Bic any reason why it wouldn't work in the fiddle? it doesnt allow me to click in the input (Adv budget). It automatically reselects the plan name select box.

Comment: What browser are you using? The test fiddle that you linked works just fine for me.

Comment: @Bic I just tried it in Chrome and it worked. However, it doesnt work for Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing some closing tags in your html. Check the plan name label and the payment term div. When you have invalid HTML, you will get different results from the each of the browsers; it all depends on how they react and interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some closing tags in your html. Check the plan name label and the payment term div. When you have invalid HTML, you will get different results from the each of the browsers; it all depends on how they react and interpret it.

```
<h4 class="plan-info-header">Plan info</h4>
    <label class="plan-name">Plan name: </label> <!-- tag wasn't closed -->
    <select id="billing-plan" name="billing-plan" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Choose plan</option>
        <option>Basic</option>
        <option>Prime</option>
        <option>Gold</option>
    </select>

    <div class="payment-term">
        <label>Billing period:</label>
        <select id="billing-price" name="billing-term" class="selectpicker" disabled>
            <option value="0">Choose billing term</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label>Advertising Budget:</label>
        <input id="advertising"></input>
    </div> <!-- wasn't closed -->

    <div class="card-charge-info">
        Your card will be charged $<span id="payment-total">0</span> now, and your subscription     will bill $<span id="payment-rebill">0</span> every month thereafter. You can cancel or change plans anytime. <!-- <span id="test">XXX</span> -->
    </div>
```

I tested in IE, which behaves similary to Safari. Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGq9q/22/)